# What clustering solutions are available in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, ejb

As a kind of follow on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040840/net-vs-ejb), what specific services are available for .NET that allow clustering in .NET similar to what is available in (Session) EJBs. The answer to the other question focused on the remote method invocation and transaction management of EJBs, but what about clustering for fail over and scalability purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [WCF best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731197.aspx), they outline how to get started with WCF load balancing.