# what is counterpart for ejb in dot net?

Tags: java, .net, ejb

i have to migrate a project written in java 1.4 with ejb 2.0 to dot net 3.5 in c#.What is the part corresponding to ejb model in dot net framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the [.NET - vs EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040840/net-vs-ejb) question here on SO which  covers this topic.